# How do I limit dnsmasq listening to only one interface?

Tags: linux-mint, dnsmasq

I've tried to have `dnsmasq` (version 2.66) listen only to the loopback interface but it obsesses on listening to *all* available addresses, i.e. *0.0.0.0:53* despite the following arguments:

```
# dnsmasq -ilo --pid-file=/run/dnsmasq-lo.pid

dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for port 53: Adress already in use
```

I have other running dnsmasq processes and they seem to listen only to one IP address:

```
# netstat -ltaupn | sed -rne 2p -e '/:53\b/p'
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 192.168.125.1:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4224/dnsmasq    
tcp        0      0 192.168.124.1:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4221/dnsmasq    
udp        0      0 192.168.125.1:53        0.0.0.0:*                           4224/dnsmasq    
udp        0      0 192.168.124.1:53        0.0.0.0:*                           4221/dnsmasq
```

When I kill all `dnsmasq` instances and re-run my command, here's what I have:

```
# dnsmasq -ilo --pid-file=/run/dnsmasq-lo.pid
# netstat -ltaupn | sed -rne 2p -e '/:53\b/p'
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4452/dnsmasq    
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN      4452/dnsmasq    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*                           4452/dnsmasq    
udp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                                4452/dnsmasq
```

The following arguments, alone or combined don't change a darn thing:

```
--local=//
-a127.0.0.1
-Ieth0 -Ieth1 -Ivirbr0 -Ivrbr1
```

How can I force `dnsmasq` to listen *only* the one interface I want, i.e. the loopback interface?

Comment: Add `--bind-interfaces`

Comment: Wut? Wait, it worked... But the help is absolutely misleading: «*Bind only to interfaces in use*» plural form! I discarded that parameter on purpose because I didn't want to bind to [all] the interfaces in use, just one and only one. Thanks **a lot** for your hint anyway. I overlooked `dnsmasq-base` being installed, it's a limited version of `dnsmasq` so I tried using only a configuration file... it worked too, even without the *bind-interfaces* clause!

Comment: The [man page](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html) is pretty clear about it. And it is interface*s* plural as you can do `--bind-interface -i lo -i br1...` to bind on the addresses on lo and br1. See also `--bind-dynamic`.

Comment: I get it. I should have read the man page as `dnsmasq --help | grep bind-interfaces` *is* misleading: «*Bind only to interfaces in use*» Reading that one did not ring the RTFMP bell. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: please feel free to answer your question with that info.

Comment: Agree man page is confusing. Generally saying your only "listening" to certain ports means you're only bound to those ports in the first place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to [stéphane-chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222264/#comment377511_222264), one possible answer is to add `--bind-interfaces`. I overlooked that option from limiting myself to reading the command line help:

```
# dnsmasq --help | grep bind-interfaces
-z, --bind-interfaces                   Bind only to interfaces in use.
```

I didn't have the reflex to double check with the man page. That help still is confusing, IMHO.

The man page however states:

```
   -z, --bind-interfaces
          On systems which support it, dnsmasq binds the wildcard address,
          even when it is listening on only some interfaces. It then  dis-
          cards  requests  that it shouldn't reply to. This has the advan-
          tage of working even when interfaces  come  and  go  and  change
          address.  This  option  forces  dnsmasq  to really bind only the
          interfaces it is listening on. About the only time when this  is
          useful  is  when running another nameserver (or another instance
          of dnsmasq) on  the  same  machine.  Setting  this  option  also
          enables multiple instances of dnsmasq which provide DHCP service
          to run in the same machine.
```

which is clearer.

Comment: Unfortunately `bind-interfaces` doesn't appear to work with `interface=eth1` for example, instead exiting with `unknown interface eth1`.