# How to disable Dnsmasq listening on Port 53, to run a Dnsmasq instance in Docker?

Tags: dnsmasq

i want to have a dockerized Dnsmasq network-wide DNS-Server-solution on my Debian 10 system.

Problem:

```
sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LIST
dnsmasq  ... TCP 192.168.122.1:53 (LISTEN)
```

There is already an instance of dnsmasq listening for local DNS-Service.
But i want to use the docker instance (pls dont ask me to use the build in dnsmasq, bc the docker one has a web interface).

In the docker-instance dnsmasq web-interface i get:

```
⁣⁣dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for port 53: Address in use
```

So its clearly, that i have to disable dnsmasq. I wen threw this thread:

https://mmoapi.com/post/how-to-disable-dnsmasq-port-53-listening-on-ubuntu-18-04

- setting `"DNSStublistener=no"`
- worked, but after reboot i got the same problem.

So obviously there is something else that i don´t understand.
This problem is linked to this Thread:

[How to correctly disable systemd-resolved on port 53 for avoiding clash with dnsmasq in Ubuntu 20.04…?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/615819/how-to-correctly-disable-systemd-resolved-on-port-53-for-avoiding-clash-with-dns)

- Same problem, but no real stress-free solution, so i assume, that it´s worth to have a new thread about it for the post-networkmanager-solution-era.

So, how can i disable that, without stumbeling into new problems?

Edit: found a solution [How do I limit dnsmasq listening to only one interface?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222264/how-do-i-limit-dnsmasq-listening-to-only-one-interface)

saying

- add `-bind interface` to config for use of multiple DNS-Servers (man page although says that)

BUT

- got a problem, bc there is no `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` file?

Answer (score 1):

I used to help myself.

1. I found the process and looked up the destination of the conf file
   with the [Classic SysAdmin: How to Kill a Process
   from the Linux Command Line](https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/how-kill-process-command-line) tutorial:

   ```
   ps aux | grep dnsmasq
   ```
2. I edited the file (e.g., `nano /var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.conf`)
   and changed the bind-dynamic to bind-interfaces

3. Rebooted to see whether it was helpful.
4. It wasn’t because the `default.conf` file is auto-generated, so it said I have to use

   ```
   virsh net-edit default
   ```

   to edit the default settings. Another problem occurred because, before v5.6 of libvirt, passing custom options was not allowed. But after that there is a special xml-phrase that I used:

   ```
      <dnsmasq:options>
        <dnsmasq:option value="foo=bar"/>
        <dnsmasq:option value="cname=*.foo.example.com,master.example.com"/>
      </dnsmasq:options>
   ```

   Solution was found in [custom dnsmasq (or custom options) with libvrt?](https://serverfault.com/q/840163); I tried that, but it didn’t work.
5. I ended up disabling DNS for the default network in the XML-File using

   ```
   <dns> <dns enable="no"/> </dns>
   ```

   Following the instructions on the man page (you write in a tmp XML and  safe, and when everything’s fine, it takes it as the new normal).
6. DNS for that port was disabled and my second dnsmasq server got up and is running.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue, except I wanted to setup pihole, and libvirt engaging dnsmasq got very much in the way. Two addendums to NASNewbie2k18's answer:

1. Adding `<dns> <dns enable="no"/> </dns>` to the default.conf file through `virsh net-edit default` didn't help, as the change was getting removed from the file after saving. Instead I had to add `<dns enable='no'/>`, so without the extra `<dns>` tags. That freed up one bind after reboot.
2. Second bind was on `10.0.3.1:53`, which is done by `lxc-net`. After changing `USE_LXC_BRIDGE` to `false` in the `/etc/default/lxc-net` file and restarting the lxc-net service with `systemctl restart`, that last bind was released, and I was finally able to launch pihole.